# python: AI language processing to extract information from short but variated texts?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I'm trying to scrape a reddit site and parse the titles. But, the titles are not in a very specific format and that things like regex don't work. In fact, there has to be some level of understanding of English.

The goal is to get the requested amount, repayment amount(s), repayment date(s), and repayment method(s).

[REQ] ($500)(#Brisbane, Queensland, Australia)(Repay $550 March 20)(PayPal)

[REQ] ($300) (#Scottsdale, AZ, USA) (Repay $360 3/17/23) (CashApp)

[Req] (400) - (#Los Angeles, Ca, USA), (Repay $440 on 3/17/23), (Cash app)

[REQ] ($150) - (#Phoenix, Arizona, USA), (REPAY $175 03/6/23), (PayPal)

[REQ] - (#Tooele, UT, US), ($300), (Payback $200 3/31/23, $200 4/30/23)

Notice how there can be a dash between [REQ] and location. And also sometimes the amount goes before the location and sometimes vice versa. For repayment, some used terms are "Repay", "payback", "pay back". For dates, some use 3/6, some say March.

The point is that there's a ton of subtle variations in these titles. We as humans can parse them, but I'm not sure how complicated a NLP model would need to be.

Comment: This seems rather easy and definitely not "NLP" as the "NL" in "NLP" stands for "natural language", but here your items are already pre-parsed into convenient parenthesised groups rather than disseminated into natural language sentences. The dash `-` is completely immaterial since your values are already safely enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: I recommend against using regexes for this.

Comment: First parse your line into a list of items. Then recognise the type of each item. There are four types: 1. amount in dollars;  2. location; 3. "repay" or "payback" followed by an amount and a date; 4. "paypal" or "cashapp".

Comment: Ah, that's a good observation. Yes, a majority of the titles have parameters enclosed in parentheses. But there are exceptions:

[REQ] ($200) (#Philadelphia, PA, USA repayment $250 03/31/23) (Cashapp, Venmo, Zelle/Paypal
___
[REQ]$500 (#Philadelphia, PA,USA) (Repay $600 4/14/23) (Venmo/PayPal)
___
[req][$130][#Stafford, VA, USA][REPAY $180 ON THURS 3/16 or EARLIER]